# Why does my C++ divide program not compile

Tags: c++

I tried to make a program that has a correct Divide function.
My code was:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double x,y,z,a;

double divide(x,y) {
    if (x >= y) {
        x=z;
        z=y;
        y=x;
        return(x/y);
    }
    else
        return(y/x);
}

int main()
{
    double x,y,z ;
    cout << "Enter x " <<endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter y " <<endl;
    cin >> y;
    a = divide (x,y);
    cout << a <<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And I have 2 errors:

```
 expected `,' or `;' before '{' token
```

on the `{` line. Right under the double divide `(x, y)` line

And another error

```
divide cannot be used as a function
```

on the `a = divide (x, y);` line.
I am using Code: Blocks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to specify a proper function signature for the function `divide`.  Specifically, the arguments to the function are missing their types:

```
double divide(double x, double y)
{
    ...
}
```

You also need to create a scope for each block in an if statement:

```
if (x > y)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Technically, the braces of an `if`/`else`/`else if` block are not required if the block contains only one line of code.

Comment: But a lot of times you should probably still put them since it'll save you hours of trouble later on if you make the mistake of thinking there *were* braces there.  :)

Answer (score 3):

The braces in an if statement don't go around the else block.  You need a separate pair of braces there.  Try:

```
    if (x >= y){
        x=z ;
        z=y ;
        y=x ;
        return(x/y);
    }
    else {
        return(y/x);
    }
```

The second set of braces (around the one line of the code after the 'else' aren't strictly necessary; you can leave the braces off an if or an else if the block is only one line long.  But while you're new you probably shouldn't, as it's easy to make mistakes that way.

Also, you have not provided types for the `x` and `y` variables in your divide function.  You must specify types for them, just as you would for any other variable.  You've written

```
    double x,y,z,a ;
```

...outside of the function, but that doesn't help; it defines *new* double variables named `x`, `y`, `z`,and `a`, completely independent of the ones in your function.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the 'optional' braces. I have witnessed many bugs in source code because people forget to add braces when they add the second line of code. For example - consider putting some kind of debug std::cout before the 'return y/x' line. I'm slowly convincing my team that always putting braces in makes for easy maintenance 6 months down the line!

Answer (score 0):

Corrected your braces in your if...else.  also need to define a type in your function's parameters.

```
using namespace std;

        double x,y,z,a ;

double divide (double x, double y)
    {
        if (x >= y){
            x=z ;
            z=y ;
            y=x ;
            return(x/y);
        }  
        else
        {
            return(y/x);
        }
    }

    int main()
{
    double x,y,z ;
   cout << "Enter x " <<endl;
   cin >> x ;
   cout << "Enter y " <<endl;
   cin >> y ;
   a = divide (x,y);
   cout << a <<endl;

        system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// divides x/y
double divide (x,y)
{
    if(y != 0)
    { 
        /*{}  <- this is called a scope.
        it is important to keep track of scopes.
        each function has it's own scope
        each loop or an if instruction can have it's own scope
        in case it does - all the instructions from the scope will be executed
        in case it doesn't - only the 1st instruction after the if/else/for/while etc. will be executed

        Here's another funny thing about scopes :
        {
            double x; // this variable exists ONLY within this scope
        }
        {
            // y doesn't exist here
            { 
                double y; // y exists here. it's local
            }
            // y doesn't exist here
        }
        */
        return x / y; 
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    double x,y;
    cout << "Enter x " <<endl;
    cin >> x ;
    cout << "Enter y " <<endl;
    cin >> y ;
    double a = divide (x,y);
    cout << a <<endl;
    cin;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are missing parameter types.